# Ember, No action handler when passing action from template to component

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to pass an action from a route to a template and then a component.

**app/routes/application.js**

```
  actions: {
    showModal(context) {
      console.log("This needs to be triggered" + context)
    },
  }
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
{{some-component 
  showModal=showModal
}}
```

**app/components/some-component/template.hbs**

```
<button {{action "showModal" "The context for the action"}}>Press Me</button>
```

When running this. I get an error saying

*"had no action handler for: showModal"*

Although, when I include the action inside **templates/application.hbs** without passing it to a component everything works fine. It's just when passing the action to a component.

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
<button {{action "showModal" "The context for the action"}}>Press Me</button>
```

This works. I want to call this action in a component though. How can I pass this action to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firing route actions is a little bit different than firing actions coming from a controller in this context. When you pass in an action to a component from a controller or another component you wrap it in the action helper like so:

```
{{some-component showModal=(action "showModal")}}
```

Since the action you're attempting to pass in lives in a route, you need to have to utilize the [send](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/Controller/methods/send?anchor=send) method from the controller to call the action in the route. You pass it into the component like so:

```
{{some-component showModal=(action send "showModal")}}
```

Here's a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/897328c324a662802e7dc766bc173046?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) that helps piece it all together.

Comment: As an alternative you may use [`ember-route-action-helper`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper). But in general I would not recommend to have such route actions. This is a pattern which is not recommended by core team. Please have a look in the discussion of the [route actions RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/394).

Comment: @stevenelberger Very detailed answer and the twiddle was a huge help. Thank you.